# Как найти суму по каждому столбцу и поместить результат в одномерный динамический массив?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

У меня есть двухмерный динамический массив, как в нём найти суму по каждому столбцу?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h> 



int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int *a,*s,*mi,*s1;
    int m, n,sum;
    int *index = NULL;
    int i,j;
    int *min = NULL;
    int *b = NULL;



    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Введите количество нас. пунктов\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Введите количество депутатов\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);


    a = (int*)malloc(m * n * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0, b = a; i < m*n; i++)
        *b++ = rand() % 200;

    for (i = 0, b = a; i < m*n; i++)
    {

        if ((i + 1) % m == 0)
            printf("\n");

        printf("%5d", *b++);
    }
    //Сума по строкам
    sum = (int*)calloc(m, sizeof(int));                

        for (i = 0, b = a, s = sum; i < m*n; i++)
        {
            *s += *b++;
            if ((i + 1) % m == 0)
                s++;
        }

        printf("\n");

        for (i = 0, b = a, s = sum; i < m; i++)
            printf("Сума по рядкам:%10d", *s++);
getchar();
return 0 ;
```

Comment: У Вас нет двумерного динамического массива. У Вас - одномерный массив, размера m * n. И кто Вам мешает прогнать два вложенных цикла для этого Вашего как бы двумерного и во внутреннем цикле считать сумму по столбцам, а во внешнем - полученную сумму складывать в ячейки одномерного массива?

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли. А как тогда задавать двухмерный динамический массив? Я только учусь и мой учитель учил задавать двухмерный динамический массив именно так.Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Декларация и выделение памяти так `int **a; a = malloc(...);`, однако здесь весь массив в одном месте и за раз, если он достаточно велик, менеджер памяти может и не переварить такое, поэтому каждую строчку придётся аллоцировать отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Так же через вложенный цикл. То есть запускаете первый цикл, затем внутри второй.